# Add Static libraries in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, static-libraries

Good morning,

Where can I declare static libraries in Eclipse. I have some *.lib files and I want to load them into the server which is a part of a GWT application.

So is there a menu point similar to "Additional Dependencies" in Visual Studio?

Best regards,
Stefan

Comment: Are those .lib-files Windows specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question, it is not possible to include *.lib files in Eclipse.

A solution is to either compile the lib as dll or wirte a dll function which wrapps around the functions of the lib.

Best regards,
Stefan